# How to write text in side the equation

Tags: equations

I have to write

```
Accelerating model: 

 f(a)=exp(-E/RT)                   (1.1)
```

I do not know how to write that. I have written:

```
\begin{equation} 
$Accelerating model$: \hspace{20 mm}     f(\alpha)= n{\alpha}^{\frac{{(n-1)}}{n} 
\end{equation}
```

but the output is

`Accelerating model: f(a)=exp(-E/RT)(1.1)`

There is no space in between the Equation and equation number.
Can anyone help me in this regards?

Comment: First, [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Secondly, there is a missing `}` closing the exponent.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `Accelerating model: 
\begin{equation} 
f(a)= \exp \left( -E/RT \right)  
\end{equation}`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a simpler way to do it, but does this help you?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \mbox{Accelerating model:} & \nonumber \\
                            &  \qquad  f(\alpha)= n{\alpha}^{\frac{{(n-1)}}{n}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need an ``align``  environment for this as you wouldn't need to put the Text into a math-style environment. Unfortunately the question of the OP doesn't get quite clear to me so I'm not sure what s/he really wants.

Comment: well, I don't find any other reason to put the text enclosed by `$` other than reverting the effect of the math mode. Thus, my interpretation is that the OP wants text mode inside an equation environment.